# How do I switch between multiple JPanels on one main JPanel with a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

This is my main panel where I'm trying to change between multiple other JPanels by clicking a JButton called "next", but when I click on the JButton nothing happens. The HomePanel stays in place the whole time.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class JCAPanel extends JPanel
{
  private HomePanel homeP;
  private ChoicePanel choiceP;
  private JButton next, quit;
  int x;
  public JCAPanel()
{
  x = 0;
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  homeP = new HomePanel();

  JPanel subpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  next = new JButton("Next");
  next.addActionListener(new ListenerNext());
  quit = new JButton("Quit");
  quit.addActionListener(new ListenerQuit());
  subpanel.add(next, BorderLayout.EAST);
  subpanel.add(quit, BorderLayout.WEST);

  add(subpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  add(homeP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public class ListenerNext implements ActionListener
{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      x++;
      if(x == 1)
      {
         choiceP = new ChoicePanel();
         add(choiceP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should read up on [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: [Lots of duplicates to be easily found](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=swing+swap+jpanels+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)

Comment: oh, I fixed it by removing the panel by the use of a button, and then adding the next panel.